# Can I hover data table to a location on scattermapbox(plotly)?

Tags: python, plotly, mapbox, scatter, plotly-dash

I am currently using plotly scattermapbox to display map locations based on radio button filters. Is it possible to mouse hover a data table on a particular location? Currently I am generating html tables using plotly dash on the web page but I have a requirement where,the same html tables must mouse hover on different locations in the map.

[image: mapbox]

Comment: Data table on hover like a tooltip!

Comment: Even https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/rich-info can also work in my case. But I am unable to implement using python-highcharts to display the same on my analytic dashboard.